# How can I specify which widget I want (e.g. a TextArea rather than a simple Text input) from a model generated form? Flask SQLAlchemy WTForms

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I've used the snippets from http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/60/ to create a WTForms form from my model in Flask. Everything works fine except from the fact that it only creates input fields. I want the description (see models.py below) to be a textarea. Any ideas?

From models.py:

```
title = db.Column(db.String(55))
description = db.Column(db.Text)
```

From views.py

```
MyForm = model_form(MyModel, base_class=Form)
form = MyForm()
return render_template('create.html', form=form)
```

From create.html

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{field.label}}
    {{field}}
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

```
<input id="title" name="title" type="text" value="">
<input id="description" name="description" type="text" value="">
```

What I want:

```
<input id="title" name="title" type="text" value="">
<textarea id="description" name="description"></textarea>
```

Comment: Which WTForms extension are you using?

Comment: from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.orm import model_form

Comment: `wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy` is deprecated in version 2 in favor of `wtforms_alchemy`. You may want to take a look at that. The other option would be to set the widget for `description` using the `field_args` argument to `model_form`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `field_args` argument of `model_form` to override settings for specific fields. You can set everything from the label to the validators. It accepts any valid argument for `Field.__init__()`, including the widget.

```
MyForm = model_form(MyModel, base_class=Form, field_args={
    'description': {'widget': TextArea()},
})
```

If you want to see what else you can override, take a look at the [source for `Field`](https://bitbucket.org/simplecodes/wtforms/src/8b7ee48d239d3ccd80b06f2044d38b0c010828fc/wtforms/fields/core.py?at=default#cl-48).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom form like so:

forms.py

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms.fields import TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField
import wtforms

class ItemForm(Form):
    title = Textfield('Title')
    description = TextAreaField('Description')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

routes.py

```
from forms import ItemForm
@app.route('/form')
def form()
    form = ItemForm()
    return render_template('form.html', form=form)
```

form.html

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{field.label}}
    {{field}}
{% endfor %}
```

This tutorial has more info: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/intro-to-flask-adding-a-contact-page/

Comment: I've been looking on some similar solutions but I don't know if that's what I want. I think it would be nice if I can generate the form directly from my model and skip the constrains to a separate form-class.

Comment: It would be nice but sometimes to get the exact results that you want you may need to back away from automatically generated results.